# How to print a number in spellings?

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement, infinite-loop

So Here I am trying to write a code, that converts a numerical number to its spelling format. For example, the user inputs any number like 320, then the output should be "Three Two Zero". Following is what I Have tried-

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
long int num,rev=0 ;
printf("Enter any number to print in words: ");
scanf("%ld",&num);
while(num!=0){
    rev=(rev*10)+(num%10);
    num/=10 ;
}
while(rev!=0){
    long int x=rev%10;
    switch(x){
        case 0:
        printf("Zero ");
        break;
        case 1:
        printf("One ");
        break;
        case 2:
        printf("Two ");
        break;
        case 3:
        printf("Three ");
        break;
        case 4:
        printf("Four ");
        break;
        case 5:
        printf("Five ");
        break;
        case 6:
        printf("Six ");
        break;
        case 7:
        printf("Seven ");
        break;
        case 8:
        printf("Eight ");
        break;
        case 9:
        printf("Nine ");
        break;
       }
   }
 }
```

Now the problem is that, this code is producing an infinite loop, like I input a number say 21, then it starts printing "Two Two Two Two........." till infinity.

Please Help me in resolving this question.

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and examine the variables as it runs. Surely you can easily find out why the infinete loop is happening. Which variable has the unexpected value that causes that (there really is only one)? What did you expect that variable value to be and why isn't it the value you expect? These are all basic questions that can be answered with even the simplest of debugging. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `long int x=rev%10;` after that, `rev=rev/10;`

Comment: `while(rev!=0)` you never change `rev` in this loop, so how do you expect it to ever become `0`?

Comment: @sittsering Yeah I got it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something that will make "rev!=0" true, which is rev = rev / 10 after the end of the switch. But creating an array and assigning zero, one, two, etc. and calling them using index could be better, I think you can think about this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
long int num,rev=0 ;
printf("Enter any number to print in words: ");
scanf("%ld",&num);
while(num!=0){
    rev=(rev*10)+(num%10);
    num/=10 ;
}
while(rev!=0){
    long int x=rev%10;
    switch(x){
        case 0:
        printf("Zero ");
        break;
        case 1:
        printf("One ");
        break;
        case 2:
        printf("Two ");
        break;
        case 3:
        printf("Three ");
        break;
        case 4:
        printf("Four ");
        break;
        case 5:
        printf("Five ");
        break;
        case 6:
        printf("Six ");
        break;
        case 7:
        printf("Seven ");
        break;
        case 8:
        printf("Eight ");
        break;
        case 9:
        printf("Nine ");
        break;
       }
       rev = rev / 10;
   }
 }
```

And this is array approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
long int num,rev=0 ;
printf("Enter any number to print in words: ");

num = 123456789;

const char arr[10][6]= {
    "Zero", "One", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"
    };

while(num!=0){
    rev=(rev*10)+(num%10);
    num/=10 ;
}
while(rev!=0){
    long int x=rev%10;
    printf("%s ", arr[x]);
    rev = rev / 10;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I got it bro, thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Suggest `const char* arr[] = { "Zero", ... , "Nine" } ;`